# Upload large files to SharePoint via MS Graph API/Postman

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, postman

I'm having some trouble making the upload of large files to SharePoint work with MS Graph API and Postman.

The thing is that I have it all working, or so it seems, but the files I upload are corrupted. If I upload say a PDF file I can't open it afterwards, although the upload process seems to go as expected.

I'm doing the following:

I get an access token and use this token to create (POST) an upload session, which gives me an URL to use for uploading file chunks.

I read the file bytes and base64 encode them into a string, which I then break up into chunks.

I set the following headers:

```
Content-Range: 0-3932159/5887320
Content-Length: 3932160
Content-Type: text/plain
```

And add the first chunk (3932160 bytes) of the base64 content to the PUT-request-body and send it with Postman.

The response indicates that this was successful and that I should send the next chunk.
And so I do the same thing again, with new header and body values.

```
Content-Range: 3932160-5887319/5887320
Content-Length: 1955160
Content-Type: text/plain
```

And the last chunk of the base64 in the PUT-request-body.

The response indicates that I was a success and I receive a lot of info about the file like a direct download URL etc.

However, the file can not be opened as it is corrupted.

I'm not sure if the making bytes into base64 and the splitting into chunks is the wrong way to do it or if the Content-Type header should indicate what the file actually is - I have tried: `text/plain, application/pdf, application/octet-stream, application/json` - but the result is always the same.

I have also tried to send the file as one single chunk, as it isn't really that big, it's just for testing and making this work - but the result is the same.

Anyone can point me in the right direction as to what could be wrong here?

Comment: Ok, I found that the base64 thing doesn't work. As soon as I send actual bytes from C# and go with 'application/octet-stream' header, the files are no longer corrupted. But how to represent these bytes in text if I wanted to try and send them with Postman (without a physical file) I still don't know.